# React Props with TS Conditional Types not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a conditional type within a component like so:

```
type Props =
  | {
      isValueNumeric: true;
      value: number;
    }
  | {
      isValueNumeric?: false;
      value: string;
    };
```

And a parent with the same comps too, but when you pass the props to the child Comp I get:

```
Type '{ value: string | number; isValueNumeric: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PropsWithChildren<TSurfaceSymbolProps>'.
  Type '{ value: string | number; isValueNumeric: boolean | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ isValueNumeric?: false | undefined; value: string; }'.
    Types of property 'isValueNumeric' are incompatible.
      Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'false | undefined'.
        Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false | undefined'.ts(2322)
```

Please check this sandbox for more info:

https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-cookies-yvj4fh App.tsx:21

CHILD COMP:

```
import React from "react";

type Props =
  | {
      isValueNumeric: true;
      value: number;
    }
  | {
      isValueNumeric?: false;
      value: string;
    };
type TSurfaceSymbolProps = React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & Props;

const SurfaceSymbol: React.FC<TSurfaceSymbolProps> = ({
  value,
  isValueNumeric,
  ...props
}) => {
  let surface;
  if (isValueNumeric === true) {
    surface = parseInt(value, 10); // just for the sake of this example
  } else {
    surface = value;
  }

  return <div>{surface}</div>;
};

export default SurfaceSymbol;
```

PARENT COMP:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Comp from "./Comp";

type Props =
  | {
      isValueNumeric: true;
      value: number;
    }
  | {
      isValueNumeric?: false;
      value: string;
    };
interface IAppProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {
  secondary?: boolean;
}

type TAppProps = IAppProps & Props;
const App: React.FC<TAppProps> = ({ value, isValueNumeric }) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Comp value={value} isValueNumeric={isValueNumeric} />
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: *"Please check this sandbox for more info:"* Please include all relevant code in the question.

Comment: When you destructure `Props` you corectly get vars with the types `var value: string|number, isValueNumeric:boolean|undefined` and these are no longer compatible to the conditional type `Props`.

Comment: @Thomas, Is there anything that can be done to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not destructure the union then everything will work:

```
const App: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SurfaceSymbol {...props} /> 
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSYBPMJOABRzAGc4BeUuOAHzgG8POg4EwBqKADYBXJADlJIJFGBoAXHBhRpAbgGC4ANwnS1AO3kAjRTr0BfAT357OwsVNnzFygPxrMEpkjWToZuakwawCYA5kGcNjpUNHAAKgDKklB+aEiplCDmEOIMEMxsiMQwAHQAEskAsgAyAIIwEeaSMEhMADy1jQAiwPoAouJICiYwAHxwAGT0jEw6pGgQJuFw6ZnoOXkF4mrI6FUAYgDC3WkZWbv5hcXMM6xwABSOBkZIADQCLp9yCiUaB+NgAlGwZu8xvAmNcdkFgJhXgBCP5uAGeNDg96cWHbbJlMAoKABACSkxeIWkXzgAEYAAygrRwAD0LLgACtJBtMNB1AALWhMFAAa1oECRMH5wjgSAAHihwGMBDZZeIAnxdHA8TcylTAiryJwiDAMiY4N0ACZDKa8HU7GzdFnW-RTHTxcirdbwJpgMCHCqVc7dB5MJ6vMCLcGsSECE1m15aq1DOBocQoJhMGSKpCsABEvrAeamWs43S2N1yd3EfEqdcjJSYqpZM1LFv5tKm1SQ4nEEDgZwglpyKBMloKcqdHZLTnbACYpqkYMT4EhrTBIlF1P2AkLcLQQCgoso4PyUH6kCZkVOF0nnTaBEzSPEgA)

Once you destructure the fields from the object typescript is not able to rebuild the original union when you assign the props (it is able to narrow them  since TS 4.6)

Comment: yeah, it seems to be working, but what if you don't want to pass all the other props down to the child Component. it's not a maintainable solution I think, but works so thank you, just hope someone can come up with sth better, if not I'll mark yours Accepted

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
type Props = BaseProps & ConditionProps

const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({ ... })
```

Write like this

```
type BaseProps =  {...}
type ConditionProps =  {...}

const Component: React.FC<BaseProps & ConditionProps> = ({ ... })
```

It will work as your expected